# Elasticsearch - dynamic field template mapping

Tags: elasticsearch

For example, I would like to make mapping for books and files. These books and files have common title field, but they are different field after that. So, I made dynamic templates (main reason to make this mapping is to let some string field set as keyword, not text).

```
   PUT my_index
    {
        "mappings" : {
            "my_type" : {
                "properties" : {
                    "title" : {
                        "type" : "keyword"
                    },
                    "props" : {
                        "dynamic" : true,
                        "dynamic_templates": [
                        {
                          "strings": {
                            "match_mapping_type": "string",
                            "mapping": {
                              "type": "keyword"
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I made like this but error comes with this.

> "reason": "Failed to parse mapping [my_type]: No type specified for
>   field [props]",

Any idea of this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dynamic template is root of type see [the link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html)

You should have smth like this

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "properties": {
        "title": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      },
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "strings": {
            "path_match":   "props.*",
            "match_mapping_type": "string",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: does It effect on field inside 'props'?

Comment: @J.Done you need to use  "path_match":   "props.*",

Comment: Thanks, You saved me :)